# MySQL - How do I horizontally fill columns

Tags: mysql

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| t_0  | t_1  | t_2  | t_3  | t_4  | t_5  | t_6  | t_7  | t_8  | t_9  | t_10 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  1   | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |  6   | N/A  | N/A  |  8   |  14  |  3   | N/A  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| N/A  |  6   |  9   |  2   |  5   | N/A  |  8   |  8   |  8   | N/A  |  N/A |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  6   | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  N/A | N/A  |  9   | N/A  | N/A  |  3   | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  | N/A  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

And I want to do a horizontal fill left to right

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| t_0  | t_1  | t_2  | t_3  | t_4  | t_5  | t_6  | t_7  | t_8  | t_9  | t_10 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  8   |  14  |  3   |  3   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| N/A  |  6   |  9   |  2   |  5   |  5   |  8   |  8   |  8   |  8   |   8  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  6   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  N/A | N/A  |  9   |  9   |  9   |  3   |  3   |  3   |  3   |  3   |  3   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

Such that the code can be generalized to any number of columns (shown here are 11, but I'd need it to work for any number)

Edit: The raw data is normalized, but I'm making an algorithm that used to be spark only run outside of spark, which is why the data is spread out the way it is

Comment: One word normilize..

Comment: Study [**this**](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization).

Comment: obviously the raw data is normalized, I'm running an app that was originally in Spark, but to bring it to production I've been "un-sparking" it and this is a step that used to be taken care of with a scala function but now needs to be done either in sql or nosql

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that is very slow query.
Don't use it if you have a choice

```
SELECT
   @x:=t_0,
   IF(t_1 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_1),
   IF(t_2 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_2),
   IF(t_3 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_3),
   IF(t_4 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_4),
   IF(t_5 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_5),
   IF(t_6 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_6),
   IF(t_7 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_7),
   IF(t_8 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_8),
   IF(t_9 IS NULL,@x, @x:=t_9),
   IF(t_10 IS NULL,@x, t_10),
FROM t
```

In most cases you should apply this kind of calculation and replacement on your backend language (php, java, .net, whatever). Try to get only raw data from MySQL but not to use it as regular language or Excel sheet. Split getting data process from transformation and representation data process. These are two different things. That could seem not obvious to you at the beginning but with time you will love this separation (I hope and I wish to you :-))

Comment: well I made an app in spark and need to do deploy it in a non-spark environment, which is why I'm doing all of this. I might switch to using a nosql database if this gets too much computation for sql to handle, as I know its not exactly what its designed to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expanded version of @Alex's answer that will work for any given table. As everyone has mentioned so far, the data should be normalized.  Seeing how convoluted all of this is should hopefully clarify why it's a bad idea.

```
SET @db = 'demo';
SET @table = 'test';
SET @firstColumn = (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=@db AND table_name=@table ORDER BY ordinal_position LIMIT 1);
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT @x:=',@firstColumn,',');
SELECT @query := CONCAT(@query,'IF(',column_name,' IS NULL,@x, @x:=',column_name,'),') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=@db AND table_name=@table ORDER BY ordinal_position;
SET @query = CONCAT( MID(@query,1,LENGTH(@query)-1),' FROM ',@db,'.',@table);
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
```